# Unify parameters names for local planner

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa, parameters, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Plugin dwa_local_planner uses path_distance_bias/goal_distance_bias/occdist_scale, but base_local_planner uses pdist_scale/gdist_scale/occdist_scale with the same semantics.
the configuration for some robots, as Turtlebot : it uses base_local_planner but sets dwa_local_planner parameters.

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/param/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml

Something similar happens with other parameters min_in_place_rotational_vel/min_in_place_vel_theta or max_rotational_vel/max_vel_theta

so which ı used parameter names are important for planners ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217756/unify-parameters-names-for-local-planner/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is where namespaces are very useful, when setting the parameters, say in a launch file you can group things

```
    <group ns="some-namespace">
        <param ....>
        ...
    </group>
```

This way, even if some parameters have similar names, every node gets the right params

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2015-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-09-28**:
I couldnt understand that how can ı use your codes exactly.